# Error: net::ERR_ABORTED 400 (Bad Request) on using AWS File Storage?[Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

[Using Python Django]

hi there I'm using aws filestorage to store files for static folder I'm using S3 bucket(free tier)

I think I have established the connection of aws with my project correctly

but still I'm getting error of
[image: net::ERR_ABORTED 400 (Bad Request)]
for every page i'm getting from aws

`settings.py`

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'camroid_app.apps.CamroidAppConfig',
    'accounts_app.apps.AccountsAppConfig',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'storages'

]

# S3 BUCKETS CONFIG

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '********************************'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '*********************************'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = '******'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

'''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
'''
```

when i click this link `'net::ERR_ABORTED 400 (Bad Request)'` i'm getting on console i get an xml page with

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
<Message>The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.</Message>
<RequestId>B9E2B024B89041D6</RequestId>
<HostId>roNnqGQVfkDBske5NMbaaPc9Rq7zYrzjLyXbGKl83EIzzb6UNT/rGbpfKNlpfGORbK3IznNZ7OM=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: Please avoid posting images of errors and also consider posting additional code to showcase your issue and additional context, we only see some settings and error messages. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Andre.IDK sorry but i think the code related to establish aws file storage connection is only this much.

Comment: if i summarize it i'm getting ```net::ERR_ABORTED 400 (Bad Request)``` on every file i have in aws bucket

Comment: i'm getting a ```net::ERR_ABORTED 400 (Bad Request)```
with link on console but when i open that link it shows
```<Error>
<Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
<Message>The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.</Message>
<RequestId>B9E2B024B89041D6</RequestId>
<HostId>roNnqGQVfkDBske5NMbaaPc9Rq7zYrzjLyXbGKl83EIzzb6UNT/rGbpfKNlpfGORbK3IznNZ7OM=</HostId>
</Error>```